# Adding secondary X-axis with user-defined list of coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have a function for plotting amount of graphics using `pyplot`. The code is here:

```
def plot_results(results, expers):
    """
    type results: list[list[float]]
    type expers: list[int]
    """
    label_builder = lambda index: 'experiment ' + str(index + 1)
    colors = ('green', 'blue')
    x_indices = list(map(compute_filesize, list(range(np.shape(results)[1]))))
    x_percents = list(map(compute_percent, list(range(np.shape(results)[1]))))

    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    for i in range(expers):
        ax1.plot(x_indices, results[i], color=colors[i], lw=2, label=label_builder(i))
    ax1.legend()
    plt.show()
```

For each value of `expers` list my function plots a chart. 
For example, `if len(results) == len (expers) == 2`, I will get such graph:[image]

I need to create the secondary X-axis (similarly to [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html), but it may be X-axis and it will be located on the top of graph).
Another difference is that **I need to set list of coordinates manually** (e.g. ax2.set_coords(x_percents)).

I created new axis using `ax2 = ax1.twinx()`. Then, I established coordinates list using `ax2.set_xticks(x_percents)`.

But because of each `x_percents[i] < x_indices[i]`, I got such picture:

[image]

(as you can see, all coordinates of new axis are located in left-bottom corner)

How can I change my function to make new X-axis:

- located on the top side of the graph,
- has its own scale, i.e. each value of `x_percents` corresponds to value of `results[i]` and
  `x_percents` dispersed throughout interval?

Comment: Do you want to actually plot data with this other axis or is this second axis just another represantation of the first?

Comment: also `np.arange(results.shape[1])` will be cleaner and faster than what yo are currently doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code suggests that `x_indices` and `x_percents` are linearly related. To keep things clear and useful for others, I'll assume the following for these 2 variables:

```
x_indices = [0, 5, 10, 25, 50]
max_size = max(x_indices)
x_percents = [ n/max_size * 100 for n in x_indices]
```

One way you could achieve creating these dual axes that relate to the same data, but just have different labels goes like this: first create an axes, then create another one *over* that (the `twinx`/`twiny` methods could be used but not strictly necessary, I'll use them here for convenience and explaining an important issue that resulted in you setting the xticks for your first axes). Then ensure the limits of both x-axes are the same, set the position of the x-ticks the same as in the first axes and finally change the labels:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vals = [1, 100, 14, 76, 33] # random data, aligned to `x_indices`
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax1.plot(x_indices, vals)
ax2 = ax1.twiny() # Remark: twiny will create a new axes 
                 # where the y-axis is shared with ax1, 
                 # but the x-axis is independant - important!
ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim()) # ensure the independant x-axes now span the same range
ax2.set_xticks(x_indices) # copy over the locations of the x-ticks from the first axes
ax2.set_xticklabels(x_percents) # But give them a different meaning
```

[image: simple example of adding two related axes to one graph]

A graph like this is frequently encountered in physics, where e.g. wavelength and energy are inversely proportionate. On one axis, you would be able to read off the units in one scale (e.g. nanometers) whereas the other would represent the same data in a different scale (e.g. electron volts).